# What do the numbers "total processed" & "total emitted" mean exactly for an Apex application

Tags: stream-processing, apache-apex

[Apache Apex](http://apex.apache.org/) application gives out few metrics when an application is running, such as "total processed" and "total emitted". What do these numbers mean exactly? Are they the number of records processed/emitted, till now, by the corresponding operator?

If above assumption is right, then, in case of, say input operator recovery, when the failed input operator is re-launched in a new container, the numbers, "total processed" and "total emitted" for input operator do not match exactly with the number of tuples fed into the input operator. Does the framework send some extra tuples, apart from the actual data tuples, in case of operator recovery?